# Are binaries compiled in Visual Studio / msbuild 100% compatible under Mono in Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, msbuild, mono

Are binaries compiled with Visual Studio or msbuild on a Windows operating system 100% compatible with running under Mono in Linux? For example could I compile the binary in Visual Studio or msbuild on Windows and then package it up to be used on Linux or would I need to build the binary using mono on a Linux operating system in order to ensure full compatibility?

Specifically I need to know if a binary generated in Visual Studio 2019 would be 100% compatible under Linux using Mono 5.10

Comment: There is no "full compatibility" on Mono. Please migrate to .NET Core.

Comment: Assuming you are using the same "supported framework" on both platforms and are not P/Invoke'ing native Windows functions, then yes. But .Net Core is replacing Mono in 2021, you really should migrate new if starting new development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, the binaries that you build on Windows will work just fine under Mono or .NET Core on Linux.  Many interfaces will work on both, although .NET Core is going to be more complete.

However, the only way to know for certain is to test.  Even if you produced perfect binaries and Mono had support for every API called, you might still use paths with backslashes in them, which Linux won't support.  You won't know that unless you run your testsuite on Linux with your desired interpreter.  This is where a suitable CI setup can help, since it lets you run most of those tests automatically.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204 Can I just clarify, would you say it's safer to build the project in mono in Linux if it's to be used in a Linux environment rather than building it on an OS that it's not intended to run on such as Windows? It seems to me the former is the more appropriate approach.

Comment: If you want to run it on Linux, I'd definitely say you should build (and test) it on Linux.  That is almost always the safer option if available.